# optional parameter not set to default value when method is called through an event subscription

Tags: c#, .net, events

I couldn't find documentation on this case, so I'd be glad to know if this behaviour is intended, and if it is, where I could find it documented.

The use case is simple: A method takes an optional parameter. In a normal method call, the argument is set to the specified default value if it is omitted in the method call.

It is also valid to hook the method to an event that doesn't supply the optional parameter (see code below for an example). However, this leads to an unexpected behaviour: instead of behaving the same (initializing the argument to the specified default value), it actually sets it to something else.

The assertion below will fail. I tested this in Unity3D 5.3.5f1 using Unity's wrapper around NUnit, but I'm pretty confident this shouldn't be Unity-specific.

I hope this question isn't too broad, but I'm really interested in why this behaviour occurs and if it is documented somewhere.

Thanks!

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using System;

public class EventWithOptionalParametersTests {

    [Test]
    public void Test() {

        Foo foo = new Foo();
        foo.OnEvent += this.HandleFooEvent;
        foo.FireEvent();

    }

    private void HandleFooEvent(bool optional = false) {
        Assert.AreEqual(false, optional); //assertion fails, optional = true
    }


    class Foo {
        public event Action OnEvent;

        public void FireEvent() {
            if(this.OnEvent != null) {
                this.OnEvent();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: For me this does not compile (in .NET 4.5): `No overload for 'HandleFooEvent' matches delegate 'System.Action'`

Comment: Optional parameters are resolved at compile-time: compiler introduces that missing parameter(s) with its specified _default_ value (see §7.5.1 Arguments Lists)

Comment: is the sample  code compiling for you ?

Comment: No the signature of HandleFooEvent does not match with OnEvent.

Comment: Thank you very much for the responses. I did some further investigation and it seems indeed that this only compiles in Unity running .Net 2.5 and, as far as I am aware of, a custom Mono compiler. I will try to gather more information on the subject, since at least working with Unity this can be an absolute hard-to-track show stopper.
 @AdrianoRepetti I think your comment would qualify as an answer in this context. If you could promote it to one I can accept it, thanks!

Comment: I did some further research. Unity's compiler targets C#4 and .Net 3.5 using their own version of the Mono C# compiler. Since the issue seems to be only verifiable in that environment, I'll see if the question would better fit on Unity's support system.